# NServiceBus for web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, nservicebus

I am implementing NServiceBus in asp.net core mvc & api application.

I have done with sending a message from asp.net mvc application. And i want to access message in api application.

I am wondering how to implement handler in api application.

Comment: Not sure if I entirey follow the question. If by API application you mean ASP.NET API which has controllers, those are not actively running, but executed when a request is coming in. Could you elaborate on your scenario and what you are trying to achieve (aside from technology usage)?

Comment: Yes. while sending data from mvc application, data should be catch to rest web api application in the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

MVC and WebAPI applications are usually configured to be `SendOnly` endpoints. They just send messages to be picked up by other endpoints. The handlers performing the actual work will be executed in the context of a different service out of IIS. That way:

- You won't have tied the long running operations to IIS so less chance of IIS reset/recycle hence breaking the app.
- You won't block the thread to perform the job. You can use WebSockets to report back to the UI if you need to (see [here](https://docs.particular.net/samples/show-case/on-premise/) for an example).
- Separate process / memory allocations so overall your application performs better.

Comment: Then what if there is need to have communication between both application?

Comment: API endpoint is not a backend service running 24/7. It only responds to the calls it receives. "What if" is not a scenario. What is it that you _actually_ trying to do?

Comment: 'What if' is the scenario for the same as there is call by the API and at that time need to get data from mvc.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your comment above, but if you need to reply back to a web browser (e.g. MVC Application) you can use SignalR to call back into the client. There are a few examples on our docs website, one is this: https://docs.particular.net/samples/near-realtime-clients/?version=core_7